# DiskBased Image cache returns null

Tags: android, android-volley

My application uses Volley networking library for caching and getting data from server, i need to cache images in disk. Here i can write data to disk but my getBitmap() method in the DiskCache always returns null.

following is my DiskCache Implementation

```
public class DiskCache  extends DiskBasedCache implements ImageCache{

public DiskCache(File cacheDir) {
    super(cacheDir);
}


public DiskCache(File rootDirectory, int maxCacheSizeInBytes) {
    super(rootDirectory, maxCacheSizeInBytes);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Entry requestedItem = get(url);

    if (requestedItem == null){
        LogUtils.LOGI("CACHE", "NO Valid Entry");
        return null;}

    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(requestedItem.data, 0, requestedItem.data.length);
}


@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final Entry entry = new Entry();

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(getByteSize(bitmap));
    bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
    entry.data = buffer.array();

    put(url, entry);
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
public int getByteSize(Bitmap bitmap){

    if(UIUtils.hasHoneycombMR1()){
        return bitmap.getByteCount();
    }
    else{
        return bitmap.getRowBytes()*bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the ImageLoader does not initialize the cache properly. Adjust your DiskCache class to call initialize(); after the super()-call.

```
public DiskCache(File cacheDir) {
    super(cacheDir);
    initialize();
}


public DiskCache(File rootDirectory, int maxCacheSizeInBytes) {
    super(rootDirectory, maxCacheSizeInBytes);
    initialize();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

Then I found out that BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray cannot decode the byte[] returned from bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer. So get decodable data using bitmap.compress.
A working example is the following implementation:

```
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            Entry entry = new Entry();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
            entry.data = baos.toByteArray();
            super.put(url, entry);
        }
```

Comment: One question? Here when you are specifying the compression format to PNG, is there a way to keep it generic so that it works well with PNG as well as JPG and so forth?